# Why do not always use Python's re.findall instead of re.search

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been learning python for some weeks. Presently I'm having some problems/questions with Python's re.findall(). 
In some books or videos they use re.search() seldom they use match(). In django documentation I read search finds the first match, and re.match finds a match at the beginning of a string.

But in all cases re.findall() would work well. So why shouldn't I use only re.findall() all the time?

As I want to get better in Python I want to understand it, therefore I asked this question.

Best regards Jonathan

Comment: Performance. `findall` always searches the whole string. `match` only checks the first part of the string and `search` can stop as soon as it finds a match. So in the best case both don't have to check the complete string.

Comment: Also, `findall()` only gives you a list of the matches as strings; it doesn't provide `Match` objects. You could use `finditer()`, but if you just wanted the first you'd need `next(finditer(...))` so you might as well use `search()`.

Comment: So when you're hungry, I assume you buy the supermarket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important reason is performance: `findall` needs to find all occurences, so it searches the whole string. `search` just searches the string until it finds a match, so provided the pattern is present it will be faster. `match` just checks if the beginning of the string matches the pattern, so it probably doesn't need to search the whole string (except in some edge cases).

So `findall` will be slower in the best case than `match` or `search`.

Additionally `findall` also stores all matches, so it can easily take much more memory than `search` or `match` which only store the first match (or nothing at all).

So `findall` is more memory expensive.

Last but not least `match` and `search` return `SRE_Match` objects which not only store the matched substring but also the position (and groups if you use patterns with capture groups). Thanks @kindall which posted this in the comments.

So, while you could use `findall` instead of `match` or `search` it can be slower, uses more memory and stores less information for the match. So I wouldn't use it as replacement for `search` or `match` except you *also* need to find all other occurences.

Comment: -@MSeifert: Thanks for your detailed answer. 
and to the others: Thx a lot for your comments